# Cannot Install Ubuntu

Tags: installation, windows-xp

I have tried many times to install Ubuntu, each time that I do I get an error stating that,
Cannot install into C:\Ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.

Comment: Welcome to AU.  Which type of installation are you attempting?  Stand-alone?  Dual boot? Wubi?  Please edit this information into your question.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing for sure, it sounds like you're attempting a Wubi installation.

If you are trying to install Wubi to the folder `C:\Ubuntu`, but that folder already exists and has files in it, the installer won't let you continue.  You need to delete that folder (and all its contents).

Open up your `C:\` drive (open `My Computer`, double click on the `C:` icon.  It may make you click `Show folder contents` before displaying the folders).  Right click on the Ubuntu folder and select move to trash.   Alternately, you could rename it in case there are important files in there you don't want to lose.  (right click -> rename -> choose new name).

Here's a Wubi [guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same issue when i using Wubi.exe application in Edububtu DVD, this happened to me because i cancel first time it start installing, then i did a permanent delete ofbi files on C:/Ubuntu. After that even the Ubuntu file not existing in the C: directory,  Wubi.exe starts shows the Error "Previous Installation find C:/ubuntu".

I googled for Wubi.exe for My ubuntu version and I downloaded Wubi.exe for Edubuntu 14.2 from http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/wubi.exe .When i started to install it prompted me with uninstall option of previous. I did that and again installed Wubi.exe From DVD.. It worked...

Comment: Welcome to AU! Wubi is now deprecated and shouldn't be used any more.